# Properties of $\aleph_1$ under axioms where $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$

Tags: set-theory, axioms, large-cardinals

There are some interesting set-theory axioms under which the cardinality of the continuum, $2^{\aleph_0}$, is equal to $\aleph_2$. One example is Woodin's Strong $\Omega$ Conjecture, though I have heard there are others.

Under such an axiom, there is a single cardinal intermediate between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, namely $\aleph_1$.

Under any such axiom, what properties of $\aleph_1$ are known? Are there known sets that it is the cardinality of?

Ideally, I'm looking for properties of $\aleph_1$ that don't require an extensive background in set theory to understand.

Edit: I'm particularly interested in simple-to-state theorems about $\aleph_1$ that hold in such a system, but are not known to hold in ZFC alone, or better yet are known to be false or unprovable in ZFC.

Comment: hi there isaacg; I have edited your title, which I believe had a typo. hopefully this is alright

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thanks for the fix!

Comment: These strong axioms tend to imply Martin's axiom, so all the usual cardinal characteristics are provably equal to $\mathfrak c = \aleph_2.$ (But there may be an interesting example I'm unaware of.)

Comment: (Also should add that there are certainly some natural constructions with size $\aleph_1$ in ZFC alone... the set of all countably ordinals being the most trivial example. The Borel ranks also come to mind. I'm just not aware of any new examples once when we add these strong forcing axioms.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Not only that, one could argue that any "natural set" is universally Baire, and under strong forcing axioms those are all satisfying CH, i.e. any universally Baire is countable or has size continuum.

Comment: Under MA (which doesn't decide the value of $\mathfrak c$, but is a consequence of PFA, which implies $\mathfrak{c}=\aleph_2$), it follows that $2^\kappa=\mathfrak c$ for every cardinal $\kappa<\mathfrak c$ (note that this implies that $\mathfrak c$ is regular). 

In particular, if MA+$\neg$ CH, $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$, which one could argue is a property of $\aleph_1$.

Comment: What kind of properties are you expecting? Is $\aleph_1$ measurable in some inner model? Some forcing axioms would imply that. But that's a technical concept. What's *not* a technical concept that involves $\aleph_1$, though? It's like asking for properties of smooth-but-not-analytic functions, but without a technical construction in analysis.

Comment: @Revilark Thanks, that's the sort of thing I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order dimension of the Turing degrees is such a cardinal. See K. Higuchi, S. Lempp, D. Raghavan and F. Stephan, On the order dimension of locally countable partial orderings, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., Vol. 148 (2020), no. 7, 2823--2833.

Comment: Would be good to elaborate the result here: the claim in this paper is that this cardinal can only be $\mathfrak c$ if $\mathfrak c$ is $\aleph_1,$ a limit cardinal, or the successor of a singular cardinal of countable cofinality (so clearly is $\aleph_1$ in the case that $\mathfrak c=\aleph_2$.) Assuming I'm reading right, seems it is an open question whether either of the latter two possibilities are consistent or if ZFC outright proves it is $\aleph_1.$